# How can I change a column of unformatted numbers so that Excel can actually read them as numbers with VBA

Tags: excel, database, vba, string, loops

The problem I've run into is that after exporting a series of data from an online source and pasting it to Excel the numbers come all wrong, essentially they are read as text instead of numbers.
I've found that this happens for two reasons:

1. There's a space " " on the end of every number
2. Numbers that are over a thousand have a "." character in the middle of them, separating the rest (e.g. 13.540,50)

In the picture below I have exactly how the numbers come to me, what I need is a code that runs for every cell in column "M" and then changes that cell, fixing the above problems so that Excel can actually read it as numbers:
[image: What shows up to me at Excel]

So at first I tried this:

```vb
Sub Fatura()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("M1:M1000")
        c.Value = Replace(c, ".", "")
        c.Value = Replace(c, " ", "")
        c.NumberFormat = "General"
        c.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Next c
```

Which worked fine but for some reason `c.value = replace(c, " ", "")` did not replace the last " " character in my string.

Then I tried this:

```vb
Sub Fatura()
    Dim c As Range
        For Each c In Range("M1:M1000")
            c.Value = Replace(c, ".", "")
            c.Value = Left(c, Len(c) - 1)
            c.NumberFormat = "General"
            c.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        Next c
```

But I get run time error '5'

Comment: What specific problems did you run into when trying to write some code for this?  It always helps here if you can show what you already tried.

Comment: `Trim$` might be helpful here, and maybe `Application.Clean` as well.

Comment: @BigBen I just tried both of those and the code ran with no erros, still that last space doesn't go away for anything. It's pretty annoying. `Sub Fatura()
    
    Dim c As Range
    
        For Each c In Range("M1:M1000")
        
            c.Value = Replace(c, ".", "")
            c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(c)
            c.NumberFormat = "General"
            c.NumberFormat = "0.00"
            
        Next c

End Sub`

Comment: You can use `CODE` and `RIGHT` to determine what that last character actually is.

Comment: @BigBen you are the man! I found out that character wasn't really a " " it was a `Chr(160)`. In other words, an annoying non-breaking space. So I've asjusted my code as follows and it now works wonders `Sub Fatura()
    
    Dim c As Range
    
        For Each c In Range("M1:M1000")
        
            c.Value = Replace(c, ".", "")
            c.Value = Replace(c, Chr(160), "")
            c.NumberFormat = "General"
            c.NumberFormat = "0.00"
            
        Next c

End Sub`

Comment: As I expected :-)

Comment: @BigBen I'm new to the platform, how can I credit you with the correct answer?

Comment: You can just self-answer here :-) Or if you prefer, I can write up a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reach an answer with @BigBen 's help.
Turns out the character at the end of my string wasn't really a space " " but a non-breaking space, wich is quite annoying. So after that discovery it was just a matter of rewriting my code as follows:

```
Sub Fatura()

Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("M1:M1000")

        c.Value = Replace(c, ".", "")
        c.Value = Replace(c, Chr(160), "")
        c.NumberFormat = "General"
        c.NumberFormat = "0.00"

    Next c
```

Thanks for the help @BigBen !!!!